# How to get year,month,quarter from the date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes start date and end date and builds a dataframe off of it. The columns I want in my dataframe are what month it is, what year it is, quater and two more columns.

I want to build the year column based on fiscal year. So a new fiscal year is July-June. So if the date is Jan 1,2021 it is Fiscal Year 2021 but August 1,2021 is Fiscal year 2022. And a quarter is 3 months, so July-Sept is Q1, Oct-Dec is Q2, Jan-March is Q3 and April-June is Q4. How do I do I add this quarter column?

Next I wanted Year context and Month Context so if the year is 2022 its current year, if it is 2021 it is 1 year ago, if it is 2020, its 2 years ago and so on. And for Month, if the date is August,2021 its current month, if it is July,2021 its 1 month ago and so on. Similarly I want a quarter context column.

Here is my code for all this: When I do this it says January as Q1 which is not correct, and I am not sure how to change it.

Its a long post but to sum up here's what I need help with:
Quarter column,year context column, month context column
Its a long post but to sum up here's what I need help with:
Quarter column,year context column, month context column, creating quarter context column

```
def create_date_table3(start, end):
  
   df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
   df = df.assign(Year=(df.date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(7)).dt.year + 1)
   current_month = datetime.now().month
   current_quarter = df["date"].dt.quarter
   current_year = datetime.now().year if datetime.now().month <= 6 else datetime.now().year + 1
   df["Month"] = df.date.dt.month
   df["Year_Month"] = df.Year.astype(str) + '_' + df.Month.astype(str)
   df = df.assign(Quarter=(df.date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(7)).dt.quarter)
   
   df["YearContext"] = ["Current Year"  if x == current_year else str(current_year - x) + ' Yr Ago'  for x in df["Year"]]
   df["MonthContext"] = ["Current Month"  if x == current_month else str(current_month - x) + ' Mo Ago'  for x in df["Month"]]
   
   return df
```